# How to make svg path clickable defined in XML file

Tags: android, android-layout, svg, svg-filters

I have an `svg`, I converted it by using [svg2android](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/), I added `xml` file in drawable folder, and consume it in `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector"
/>
```

This is drawing 3 dots (from path data) in my screen, and i want to make all these dots clickable, when user clicks on them i want to change these dots color from black to white.

Following is the data in my `xml` file, converted from `svg`.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="400dp"
    android:height="400dp"
    android:viewportWidth="400"
    android:viewportHeight="400">

    <path
        android:name="EM_S030_F0001_L0230"
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="M 96.1 353 L 100.6 350.8 L 102.8 355.2 L 98.4 357.4 Z" />
    <path
        android:name="EM_S030_F0001_L0228"
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="M 101.8 350.3 L 106.5 348.6 L 108.2 353.2 L 103.5 355 Z" />
    <path
        android:name="EM_S030_F0001_L0226"
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="M 107.9 348.2 L 112.5 346.5 L 114.2 351.1 L 109.6 352.8 Z" />
```

Comment: you need a custom view for this feature: there is no support in android for things like that

Comment: You can change your image tint or make a custom view as pskink suggested

Comment: Thanks @pskink & Ibrahim, but in customView, i will be rendering <Path> data, do you know any example regarding this.

Comment: sure: search for `PathParser.java` - it is in `support-vector-drawable` package

Comment: Thanks, will look into this

Comment: @Kirmani88 Were you able to resolve this issue?.Please let me know i am stuck at this point.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.vector_white); 
        }
    });
```

vector_white.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="400dp"
android:height="400dp"
android:viewportWidth="400"
android:viewportHeight="400">

<path
    android:name="EM_S030_F0001_L0230"
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:pathData="M 96.1 353 L 100.6 350.8 L 102.8 355.2 L 98.4 357.4 Z" />
<path
    android:name="EM_S030_F0001_L0228"
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:pathData="M 101.8 350.3 L 106.5 348.6 L 108.2 353.2 L 103.5 355 Z" />
<path
    android:name="EM_S030_F0001_L0226"
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:pathData="M 107.9 348.2 L 112.5 346.5 L 114.2 351.1 L 109.6 352.8 Z" />
```